# How much protection do the various shields give

Tags: ingress

With the new levels of shields available as of 3 June 2013, is there an indication of how much protection each shield will give a portal?

Similarly, do they contribute to the XM drain on the attacker in any way?

For info on the new buffed shields, check out [decodeingress](http://decodeingress.me/2013/06/03/portal-shields-are-stronger-now-but-only-new-ones/):

> Brandon Badger published on 31st of May that Portal Shields feel
> stronger now. But there is a catch, only new obtained portal shields
> are stronger. If you farmed those shields in last few months they have
> same stats as old shields. Only new farmed shields have new stats:
>
> Old shields:  Common +6
> Rare +8
> Very Rare +10
>
> New shields: Common +10 Rare
> +20 Very Rare +30

Comment: Source for new levels of shields?

Comment: http://decodeingress.me/2013/06/03/portal-shields-are-stronger-now-but-only-new-ones/

Comment: Well I guess with those mitigation values, we have some relative understanding that V shields are now 3x better. Although we still aren't much closer to completely understanding mitigation.

Comment: Yeah - that's about my level of understanding :-) Was hoping for someone to explain how they mitigate eg will one V shield mean I require 10 more L6 XMP - that sort of thing.

Comment: "What is the formula for dmg mitigation?"
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133484/37896

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you assumed, new shields mitigations are :

- common shield : 30
- rare shield : 40
- very rare shield : 60
- AXA shield : 70

You can see those values in the app when upgrading shields.

Note that those values are for newly obtained shields, old one will still have old mitigation's values.

The mitigation of the shields is a percentage of absorption of damages. A (common) shield with a mitigation of 10 will absorb 10% of the damages made by the buster. A second (common) shield with mitigation 10 will catch 10% of the remaining damages.

For example, let's imagine a burster making 100 of damages on a resonator. First common shield will absorb 10% so damages will be reduced to 90. A second common shield will absorb 10% of the 90 damages and will reduce damages to 81...

In the worst/better case with 4 very rare shields mitigation 30, a burster making 100 damages will be reduced to 24.

To compute the total mitigation of shields on a portal you have to just multiply the percentages. A very rare shield will eat 30%, to compute the effects you'll have to do `X - (X * 30 / 100)` that will reduce to `X * 0.7`.
So a very rare shield is equal to a 0.7 factor applied on the burster's damage, a rare shield is equal to 0.8 and a common to 0.9.

So the way of computing damages is :

```
RESULTING_DAMAGES = BURSTER_DAMAGES * SHIELD_1_FACTOR * SHIELD_2_FACTOR * SHIELD_3_FACTOR * SHIELD_4_FACTOR
```

And no matter the order of the shields, the result of a * is always the same :)

Comment: What I never understood is: how does that work with mixed shields? Are the most powerful counted in first? or the least powerful ones? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: @Kappei : I would say "no matter the order", they all count in the same time. I edited my answer with more detailled computes.

Comment: My mind for a moment completely forgot any notion regarding multiplications, sorry about that :P

Comment: This answer is very much outdated.

Comment: @Qwerty : I updated the answer with new values... yet you could suggest an edit to improve an already existing answer ;-)

Comment: I can't edit your answer because I would have changed it way too much. Nothing you say applies any more. That shields won't upgrade was indeed correct two years ago, but not any more. And shield's mitigation does not stack multiplicatively, it never did. I know there were many theories, but it was stated by NIA that mitigation stacks additively.

Answer (score 0):

The shield mitigation changed <del>once again</del> and again

```
Common shield    = 30  
Rare shield      = 40  
Very Rare shield = 60  
AXA shield       = 70
```

<del>It was possible to *renew* all old shields by dropping them on ground, but it's not longer necessary.</del>
  For more up to date information, and to see mitigation of links see 
[this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133484/37896).

[What is the formula for damage mitigation in Ingress?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133484/37896)