# Ingress: Softbank ultra links vs. shields

Tags: ingress

I sometimes wonder whether I should put a "Softbank ultra link" or a shield on an Ingress portal for protection.  I assume the answer depends on how many link are attached to the portal.  But how many links are required to make an ultra link better than a common/rare/very rare/AXA shield?

Comment: Related question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/120525/108302

Answer (score 6):

Here is an attempt to answer my own question: Looking at the "Portal Defense Boost % based on Number of Links" picture in https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133484/100574 , the defense boost provided by links is always below 60 (at least for portals with <=10 links).  Assuming that an ultra link just adds 50% extra to this, the extra mitigation provided by an ultra link should always be less than 30.  If this is right, even a common shield (mitigation 30) would always provide better protection than an ultra link.

(Since I am unsure whether I understand the referenced answer correctly, I would be happy to receive alternative answers from people who have some actual knowledge about this.)

Comment: I think your response is right. If you really need protection, you will put AXA or VRS anyway. The stickiness factor is also important to consider, if your mod is destroyed it will not protect anymore, and ULA has 0 stickiness.

Comment: I know it says +1.5x Link Defense, but is it +50% or +150% link mitigation? I think it's the former, because Force Amps say +2x when it's really only +1x, but if it is the latter then that makes them a lot stronger thans shields for mitigation (though the stickiness is still abysmal).